# RAP installation and necessary things to include while installation

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, osgi, eclipse-rap

I'm facing problem in my Rap application since i m new to this platform 
As per the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&v=6dAdpNjoBSc&NR=1..
i have done according to the video but idoubt ther might be few mistakes in my installation. i have to work with Oracle and jboss...

i have encountered with errors as follows

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.rap.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-02-06 16:36:30.640
>   !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle
>   "org.eclipse.rap.ui.workbench_1.5.1.20120917-1116 [3]" could not be
>   resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package:
>   org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi; version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that you include the bundle `org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi` in your launch configuration? See http://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/FAQ#My_application_is_not_running_after_switching_to_RAP_1.5